# Math / statistics problem analyse words in string

Tags: php, math, statistics

In need of some help - am trying to analyse news articles.
I have a list of positive words and negative words. I am search the article contents for instances of the words a counting the up.

my problem is that the negative word list is a lot long that the positive so all the results a skewed to negative.

I am looking for a way to normalise the results so a positive word is weighted slightly against the negative to even out the fact that is a considerably high chance of finding a negative word. Unfortunately I have no idea where to start.

Appreciate you taking the time to read this.

Below is the code I have so far.

```
  function process_scores($content)
  {
    $positive_score = 0;
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->positive_words); $i++) {
      if($this->positive_words[$i] != "")
      {
        $c = substr_count( strtolower($content) , $this->positive_words[$i] );
        if($c > 0)
        {
          $positive_score += $c;
        }  
      }
      
    }
    
    $negative_score = 0;
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->negative_words); $i++) {
      if($this->negative_words[$i] != "")
      {
        $c = substr_count( strtolower($content) , $this->negative_words[$i] );
        if($c > 0)
        {
          $negative_score += $c;
        }
      }
    }
      
    return ["positive_score" => $positive_score, "negative_score" => $negative_score];
    
  }
```

Comment: Not sure if [PHP Sentiment Analyzer](https://github.com/davmixcool/php-sentiment-analyzer) may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know php, but this seems less like a php question and more of a question of method. Right now when you analyze an article, you assign words as positive or negative based on whether or not they are in your dictionary, but because your dictionaries are of different sizes, you feel like this isn't giving you a fair analysis of the article.

One method you could try is to assign each word in the article a value. If a word does not exist in your dictionary, have the program prompt for manual interpretation of the word through the command line. Then decide whether the word is positive, negative, or neutral, and have the program add that word to the appropriate dictionary. This will be really annoying at first, but English speakers use roughly the same 2000 words for almost all of our conversation, so after a few articles, you will have robust dictionaries and not have to worry about skew because every single word will have been assigned a value.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just throwing in a weighting factor to the output.  The exact weighting is determined by trial and error.  I went ahead and refactored your code since there was some repetition

```
<?php

class WordScore {
    private $negative_words = [];
    private $positive_words = [];
    
    private $positive_weight = 1;
    private $negative_weight = 1;
    
    public function setScore(float $pos = 1, float $neg = 1) {
        $this->negative_weight = $neg;
        $this->positive_weight = $pos;
    }
    
    public function processScores($content) {
        $positive_score = $this->countWords($content, $this->positive_words);
        $negative_score = $this->countWords($content, $this->negative_words);
        
        return [
            "positive_score" => $positive_score * $this->positive_weight, 
            "negative_score" => $negative_score * $this->negative_weight
            ]; 
    }
    
    private function countWords( string $content, array $words, float $weight = 1 ) {
        $count = 0;
        foreach( $words as $word ) {
            $count += substr_count( strtolower($content) , strtolower($word) );
        }
        return $count;
    }
    
}
```

working example at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/19b4ac3c12d35cf253e9fa6049e91508e4797a2e